# Database normalization : where does unit price stands?

Tags: database-normalization

I'm having confusion whether i should put unit price of item in Item table or Order table?

Given table:

**SalesOrderNo**, Date, CustomerNo, CustomerName, CustomerAdd, ClerkNo, ClerkName, ItemNo, Description, Qty, UnitPrice

I did this solution:

1. SalesOrderDetail: **SalesOrderNo**, **CustomerNo**, Qty, ClerkNO
2. Customers:        **CustomerNo**, CustomerName, CustomerAdd
3. Clerks:           **ClerkNo**, ClerkName
4. Items:            **ItemNo**, UnitPrice, Description

But MAM gave following solution:

1. Customers:          **CustomerNo**,             CustomerName, CustomerAdd
2. Clerks:         **ClerkNo**,            ClerkName
3. Inventory Items:    ItemNo,             Description
4. Sales Orders:       **SalesOrderNo**,       Date, CustomerNo, ClerkNo
5. SalesOrderDetail:   **SalesOrderNo**, **ItemNo**,    Qty, UnitPrice

Which one is right?
And specifically unit price, shouldn't it depend on item rather then order?

Comment: What do Items is used for? In my point of view UnitPrice should be on SalesOrderDetail, but i can't understand your original solution.

Comment: I supposed Items table is same as product table.

Comment: Typically, the price is duplicated in the order because the order should reflect the price at the time the order was made, rather than the *current* price of the item.

Comment: i would say your sol is the right one, but @IanMcLaird have a point , price should be archived with order, as it may got changed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about all the scenarios where this data will be used.  I would actually say that the `UnitPrice` in fact goes on *both* tables.

When looking at a catalog or inventory report, users may wish to see what the current asking price for each `Item` is, and that price is dependent only on the `Item`.  However, when an order is placed, there may be a reason to alter the price for that order, without changing the normal price of the item.  Perhaps the salesman had to give a little discount in order to make the sale.  Perhaps the item was part of an incentive program.  Maybe next week the asking price of the item will go up because of supply chain issues, but any orders already processed need to retain the price at the time they were made (otherwise, the invoices won't balance).